# Sum of a certain Series: Where is the error?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series:

- $ \displaystyle \cdots + \frac{1}{z^{3}} + \frac{1}{z^{2}} + \frac{1}{z} + 1 + z + z^{2} + z^{3} \cdots$

This series can be summed in the following way:

$$\cdots + \frac{1}{z^{3}} + \frac{1}{z^{2}} + \frac{1}{z} + 1 = \frac{z}{z-1}$$ and $$ z + z^{2} + z^{3} + \cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}$$

So the sum equals $0$.

Is this correct or wrong? Please let me know if there is any error.

Comment: I don't understand the -1. This is a genuine question people might have.

Comment: @Moron: Perhaps, people might think that as a graduate student i should have done this.

Comment: @Chandru: People should (usually) be judging the content, not the poster. But I guess that could be one reason...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is the following: Your first summation only holds for $\lvert z\rvert >1$ while the second one only holds for $\lvert z\rvert <1$.

Comment: Nice observation.

Comment: @Chandru1: But you knew that already, didn't you? So why did you ask this question?

Comment: @TonyK: What did i know? Look, don't conclude anything yourself.

Answer (score 8):

This series does not converge for any complex value of $z$.  However, in a certain sense if you set $z = e^{2 \pi i t}$, this is the Fourier series of the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

In any case, you can show that *if* there is a consistent way to interpret the sum, then for $z \neq 1$ it must be $0$.  This is because the expression $f$ satisfies $f = zf$.

(It is possible to work abstractly with two-sided Laurent series, but you cannot multiply them, and you cannot evaluate them anywhere; the best you can do is consider them as a module over the Laurent polynomials.  This is done, for example, in certain branches of mathematical physics.)